# Naming HTML input arrays as [] or [0]?

Tags: php, html, arrays

I need to create multiple forms with a single submit (save) button.

```
<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($c); $i++): ?>

    <div>            
        <input type="radio" name="gender[<?php echo $i ?>]" id="gender_<?php echo $i ?>_male" value="male" />
        <label for="gender_<?php echo $i ?>_male">Male</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender[<?php echo $i ?>]" id="gender_<?php echo $i ?>_female" value="female" />
        <label for="gender_<?php echo $i ?>_female">Female</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div><label for="Name_<?php echo $i ?>">Name:</label></div>
        <div><input type="text" name="Name[]" id="Name_<?php echo $i ?>" /></div>
    </div>    

<?php endfor ?>
```

I had to [name the radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619163/radio-buttons-array-elements) as gender[0] ... gender[1] so that the groups have unique names.
But I've named Name as Name[].

My question is, do I name Name[] as Name[0] ... Name[1] instead so that the flow is constant ?
I mean, *can* $_POST['Name'][0] ever be mapped to gender[1] ?

Comment: _"can $_POST['Name'][0] ever be mapped to gender[1] ?"_ .... what? No, that would defeat the entire purpose of naming ANYTHING if it could be assigned differently by "random" - Other than that, see Marc B's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers TEND to submit fields in the same order they're listed in the html, but as far as I know, there's no REQUIREMENT this be the case. So, if you had

```
<input name="foo[]" ...>    ... should become $_POST['foo'][0]
<input name="foo[]" ...>    ... should become $_POST['foo'][1]
<input name="foo[]" ...>    ... should become $_POST['foo'][2]
```

But since there's no requirement, you may well get the fields in some OTHER order. If you're using the `[]` naming hack, and doing multiple fields that must be associated with each other, you may be better off explicitly listing indexes, to ensure that the field association is maintained, e.g.

```
<input name="firstname[0]"> <input name="lastname[0]">
<input name="firstname[1]"> <input name="lastname[1]">
etc...
```

Without this, your user name could enter `John Doe` and `Jane Smith`, but receive `John Smith` and `Jane Doe` at the server. Not very likely, but... better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers will always submit fields in the same order. This is required by [the HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#constructing-form-data-set):

> Loop: For each element field in controls, **in tree order**, run the following substeps:

So, unless you start disabling fields, you won't have a problem.

Being explicit might make it a little easier to read your code though.